# Rickshaw - max and min value from this jsp library in RangeSlider

Tags: rickshaw

I using this jsp library for graph generating. And I want write function, that show me onli error messages at graph time (actual graph min <-> actual graph max)..
Functions is:

```
i = 4700;
while (i < 4800) {
    if(i<ui.values[0]){
        $("."+i).hide();  
    }
    else if(i>ui.values[1]){
        $("."+i).hide();  
    }
    else {
        $("."+i).show();  
    }
    i++;
}
```

But I dont know, where can I take globalGraph maximum value and global graph min value.

So, anybody with expirience in this jsp library? :)

Answer (score 0):

Okey, solved.

In Rickshaw.Graph.RangeSlider.js -> slide: function( event, ui ):

```
                i = ui.values[0]-100;
                while (i < (ui.values[1] + 100)) {

                    if(i<ui.values[0]){
                        $("."+i).hide();  
                    }
                    else if(i>ui.values[1]){
                        $("."+i).hide();  
                    }
                    else {
                        $("."+i).show();  
                    }
                    i++;
                }
```